# Laravel "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with Laravel migrations.
I did everything by the book, migrations are working fine, but when I try to install laravel passport with uuids, It's giving me an error that table countries "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".
I tried to add

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
```

in down function, but no success.

This is how my migrations looks like:

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('currency_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('iso_alpha_2')->unique();
            $table->string('iso_alpha_3')->unique();
            $table->string('native_name');
            $table->integer('phone_code');
            $table->string('capital')->nullable();
            $table->string('continent')->nullable();
            $table->json('languages')->nullable();
            $table->text('address_format')->nullable();
            $table->string('flag')->nullable();
            $table->text('time_zone')->nullable();
            $table->string('locales')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies');

        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Full error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `ecomet_git`.`countries` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: create table `countries` (`id` char(36) not
> null, `currency_id` char(36) null, `name` varchar(255) not null,
> `iso_alpha_2` varchar(255) not null, `iso_alpha_3` varchar(255) not
> null, `native_name` varchar(255) not null, `phone_code` int not null,
> `capital` varchar(255) null, `continent` varchar(255) null,
> `languages` json null, `address_format` text null, `flag` varchar(255)
> null, `time_zone` text null, `locales` varchar(255) null, `created_at`
> timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `deleted_at` timestamp
> null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
>
> at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\eComet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
> 674â–•         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 675â–•         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 676â–•         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 677â–•         catch (Exception $e) {   âžœ 678â–•             throw new QueryException(
> 679â–•                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 680â–•             );
> 681â–•         }
> 682â–•
>
> 1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\eComet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ecomet_git`.`countries` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed")")
>
> 2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\eComet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
> PDOStatement::execute()

Comment: What is the column type for id on currencies? It must match currency_id exactly.

Comment: It's uuid.. the migration is working, only when I try passport install is not working

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question